# Preposition usage in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Which word out of "for" and "to" should I use in the following sentence:

> The board has issued roll number slips **to/for** private candidates.

Answer (score 2):

They mean different things.

> The board has issued roll number slips **to** private candidates.

means the slips are given (issued) to the candidates.

> The board has issued roll number slips **for** private candidates.

Here *for* indicates the purpose of the slips (they have something to do with the candidates).